# Determinant of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $V = \mathbb R^n$, $f$ the standard scalar product and $\{b_1, \cdots , b_n\}$ a basis of $V$ , and $\{b_1^*, \cdots, b_n^*\}$ an orthogonal basis of $V$ obtained with Gram-Schmidt algorithm. Let $B = (b_1 \cdots b_n) \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $B^* = (b_1^* \cdots b_n^*) \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ the matrices where the vectors of the basis are columns. Show that $\lvert \det(B) \rvert = \Pi_{i=1}^n \lVert b_i^* \rVert _2$

I have shown that $B=B^*M$ where $M$ is a triangular matrix with $\det(M)=1$. So $\det(B)=\det(B^*)$. Now I don't really know what to do and how to link $\det(B^*)$ with the norms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different people mean different things by "the Gram-Schmidt algorithm". I first understood this to mean the process that ends up with an orthonormal basis - I always normalise the vectors are I go along, and so wouldn't get this result.

However, I take it that you do not normalise the vectors and so get an orthogonal set of vectors $b_1^*,b_2^*,\dots, b_n^*$, with as you say $BM=B^*$ where $M$ is unitriangular.

Now let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with $(i,i)$-entry $1/\lVert b_i^* \rVert$.

Then $BMD=\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is orthogonal, and so has determinant $\pm1$.

Taking determinants we now have $\det B=\prod_{i=1}^n \lVert b_i^* \rVert  \cdot \det\Omega$.